# How to remove the classes that begin with a certain string?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to remove the classes that begin with a certain string.

Here is my code:

```js
function myfunction() {
  const body = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
  body.classList.remove('page*'); //remove page-parent
}

myfunction();
```

```html
<div class="page-parent pop">
  check out
</div>
```

Comment: I looking the way to remove the class name by pure javascript, not using jquery

Comment: Look at the second answer, it's pure JavaScript.

Comment: Seriously, I wish people would take time to understand the question before marking it as duplicate. The other question asked for a jQuery solution, which is very heavy handed. Although there are pure JavaScript solutions, a question tagged with jQuery is likely to be overlooked by others looking for a pure JavaScript solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple example by using loop regular expression check and remove item which is matched.

```js
function myfunction() {
  var div = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
  
  var matches = [];
  div.classList.forEach(function (value) {
    //remove page-parent
    if (/^page.+/.test(value)) {
      matches.push(value);
    }
  });
  matches.forEach(function (value) {
      div.classList.remove(value);
  });
}

myfunction();
```

```html
<div class="page-parent pop">
  check out
</div>
```

Comment: I have only single class at time, without loop can't we do?

Comment: @Gras Double Thanks for correct the error of my carelessness

Comment: @3gwebtrain loop is for checking all of the classes. Built-in method or any other method also do loop I think.

Answer (score 9):

OK , there are many solution to this

first what causes your problem ?

in your code you just remove the class that should be `page*` and that's not a regular expression because you're using the double quotes .

also `classList` is a [DOMTokenList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList) which is a collection , so we need to iterate over it to test each value in the list to see if it meets specific criteria

how to solve this problem ?

first solution

use [startWith](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) string method

how ?

1. iterate over each class in classList  check if it starts with what
   you search for  remove it if yes

example

```js
const p = document.getElementById('p');
p.classList.forEach(item=>{
    if(item.startsWith('page')) {
        p.classList.remove(item) ;
    }
})
```

```css
.page-blue {
    color: blue;
}
.c {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
}
```

```html
<p id="p" class=" c page-blue">
    hello I am p
</p>
```

also you can use simple regular expression for that

how ? 
using [special-caret](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-caret) that tests if the input starts with the specified value

example

```js
const p = document.getElementById('p');
p.classList.forEach(item=>{
    if(/^page/.test(item)) {
        p.classList.remove(item) ;
    }
})
```

```css
.page-blue {
    color: blue;
}
.c {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
}
```

```html
<p id="p" class=" c page-blue">
    hello I am p
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very "ES6" way of doing it.

We're converting the `classList` into an array with a [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) then we are filtering the array with `regex`. This leaves us with an array of classes we want to remove so we can do a `forEach` over them and remove them.

I've used a little CSS to display the `div`s classes next to it.

```js
const body = document.querySelector('div');

[...body.classList].filter(c => {
  return c.match(/^page.*/)
}).forEach(e => {
  body.classList.remove(e)
});
```

```css
div:after {
  content: "("attr(class)")";
}
```

```html
<div class="page-parent pop">
  check out
</div>
```

I hope you find this helpful.